# To understand concept of connectedness and compactness of $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

I have studied basic calculus and allied stuff but not topology . Can anyone explain these concept in real  line only without the use of topology .

how to check compactness and connectedness of this set ?
 {$x^2/(x^2+1): x\in \mathbb R  \} $.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking whether the set $\{\frac{x^2}{x^2+1} : x \in \Bbb R\}$ is connected and compact, as a subspace of $\Bbb R$? Compactness and connectedness are topological concepts (or at least, concepts about metric spaces), so I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for that doesn't use topology.

Comment: Do you mean to ask if the range of the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + 1}$, namely $[0, 1)$, is compact and/or connected?

Comment: Connectedness & compactness are topological concepts .How to explain them without topology?

Comment: @manthanomen yes exactly that im looking for ! please explain

Comment: connected but not compact

Comment: @manthanomen  seen ur answer can you guide me further on this topic i mean some more examples , any article on this perhaps or book for this specific need . thanks

Comment: @godonichia How much real analysis do you know? Have you been introduced to connectedness/compactness in arbitrary metric spaces? If not, where did you see these definitions?

Comment: @manthanomen i know about basic open ,closed , limit point , derived sets and all that stuff which im studying now.i havent studied any topology , this question was im ,y one of past papers which i had no idea about .course name is elementary real analysis

Comment: @godonichia The best thing would be to ask the professor of your analysis class where you can learn about concepts like connectedness and compactness. He/She would have a better understanding of your background and be able to give you a suitable reference. If you want to look on your own, the classic reference for real analysis is Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis," and the classic reference for topology is Munkres' "Topology".

Comment: @manthanomen thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + 1}$ is the interval $[0, 1)$. A set in the real line is connected if and only if it is an interval or a one point set, so $[0, 1)$ is indeed connected. Furthermore, compact sets in the real line are closed and bounded. The set $[0, 1)$ is bounded, but it isn't closed (it doesn't contain all its limit points, namely $1$), so this set is not compact.